# How to get average disk queue length of a physical hard drive based on folder path

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems

I want to check what is the disk queue length of a physical hard drive, on which a specified folder is stored e.g. /home/andy250/myfiles
I want to check this automatically via script.

I am running Azure Linux VM (Ubuntu 20.04). Running `df /home/andy250/myfiles` gives me this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       30309264 16460592  13832288  55% /
```

And then when I run `iostat -x` I get this

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.82    0.01    0.39    0.07    0.00   98.70

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
loop0            0.01      0.37     0.00   0.00    0.18    41.25    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop1            0.02      0.83     0.00   0.00    0.42    51.09    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop10           0.05      1.48     0.00   0.00    0.06    29.10    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop11           0.00      0.03     0.00   0.00    0.27    21.31    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop12           0.01      0.36     0.00   0.00    0.07    62.18    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop13           0.05      2.16     0.00   0.00    0.24    45.46    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop14           0.02      0.72     0.00   0.00    0.05    38.69    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.01
loop15           0.00      0.02     0.00   0.00    0.10    18.17    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop16           0.02      0.74     0.00   0.00    0.03    38.20    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.01
loop17           0.05      1.44     0.00   0.00    0.04    27.94    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop2            0.03      0.39     0.00   0.00    0.10    12.35    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop3            0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.20     1.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop4            0.04      0.50     0.00   0.00    0.07    13.31    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop5            0.04      0.47     0.00   0.00    0.07    12.60    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop6            0.07      1.05     0.00   0.00    0.08    14.19    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.01
loop7            0.06      1.50     0.00   0.00    0.11    25.58    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.01
loop8            0.09      0.28     0.00   0.00    0.04     2.97    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
loop9            0.01      0.33     0.00   0.00    0.11    37.36    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
sda              1.02     26.82     0.08   7.04    0.85    26.31    1.31     45.36     0.98  42.76   14.55    34.66    0.11     59.70     0.00   0.49   10.11   561.47    0.02   0.32
sdb              0.00      0.02     0.00   0.00    0.29    29.83    0.00      0.54     0.00  60.32    3.06   479.99    0.00     54.03     0.00  50.00    0.07 242163.65    0.00   0.00
```

So the problem is that `df` shows a "Filesystem" that does not exist on the list of "Devices" in output of `iostat`. I am probably missing some fundamentals on how linux filesystem works, but I want to somehow figure out on which device the folder `/home/andy250/myfiles` (Filesystem `/dev/root`) physically exists - so I can parse the correct line of `iostat` output or just run `iostat -dx [device id]`.

**EDIT**
Output from `lsblk`

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1     7:1    0 135.1M  1 loop /snap/chromium/1912
loop2     7:2    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284
loop3     7:3    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop4     7:4    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1328
loop5     7:5    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1361
loop6     7:6    0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop7     7:7    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop8     7:8    0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop9     7:9    0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14978
loop10    7:10   0 346.8M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-runtime/286
loop11    7:11   0   5.9M  1 loop /snap/notepad-plus-plus/346
loop12    7:12   0 134.8M  1 loop /snap/chromium/1926
loop13    7:13   0 322.9M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/14
loop14    7:14   0  67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop15    7:15   0     6M  1 loop /snap/notepad-plus-plus/349
loop16    7:16   0  67.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22526
loop17    7:17   0 346.9M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-runtime/287
sda       8:0    0    30G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  29.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0    16G  0 disk 
└─sdb1    8:17   0    16G  0 part /mnt
```

**EDIT 2**
Output from `ls -al /dev/root`:

```
brw------- 1 root root 8, 1 Feb 28 08:17 /dev/root
```

Output from `stat "$(realpath /dev/root)"`

```
File: /dev/root
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 160         Links: 1     Device type: 8,1
Access: (0600/brw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-02-28 08:18:15.753244000 +0000
Modify: 2022-02-28 08:17:56.732000000 +0000
Change: 2022-02-28 08:17:56.732000000 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Just curious, what does `ls -l /dev/root` give you? (And perhaps even, `stat "$(realpath /dev/root)"`)

Comment: @TomYan updated my question with the outputs

Comment: Seems like it's an additional dev node that refers to the same block device as `/dev/sda1` does. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mknod.1.html for your reference and research about major minor.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem and physical block devices are different things, so you can not expect to find an `sd*` for each filesystem reported by `df`.

I suspect your `/dev/root` block device to be a symlink pointing to a device mapper (or LVM) disk. Please show the output of `lsblk` and `pvs; vgs; lvs` to confirm.

That said, your `iostat` output only shows `sda` and `sdb` (the various `loop` devices are for snaps) and so your root devices can only be backed by these two disks.

**EDIT:** your `lsblk` output clearly shows that `/dev/sda1` is mounted as the root filesystem. The `/dev/root` entry is probably symlinked to `/dev/sda1` (a thing you can check with `ls -al /dev/root`).

Comment: edited my question with output from lsblk. The other 3 commands give me empty output.

Comment: @andy250 I've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, updated question with output from `ls -al /dev/root` and also `stat`

Comment: @andy250 The output of `lsblk` already shows your root device - which is `sda1`. No need to update the question with additional details from my part.

Comment: I still have no idea how I could get from `/home/andy250/myfiles` to `sda` using a script. There seems to be too much guesswork or hidden knowledge to be able to resolve my path to `sda` in this case.